# Doesn't django implement Content Security Policy by default?

Tags: django, content-security-policy

In a RoR project I had `<%= csp_meta_tag %>` in the main html file.

I was trying to build a conceptual app in Django with the knowledge I had at RoR, but when searching for Django Content Security Policy, only a extension appears (https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

There is no documentation regarding the topic so, is it possible that Django does not solve this common security issue by default?

Also, I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635692/django-content-security-policy-directive) SO question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [`django-security` package](https://github.com/sdelements/django-security) but it [supports not all](https://csplite.com/csp207/#django-security) existing CSP tokens and directives.

I think that Python programmers just use the [HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields)  to do such simple things as to issue CSP HTTP header.

But it's interestingly, Django has built-in middleware to manage [X-Frame-Options header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#x-frame-options-middleware), but there is no similar for the CSP.
And the removal of the long-unsupported `X-XSS-Protection` header is [planned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.0/#securitymiddleware-no-longer-sets-the-x-xss-protection-header) in Django 4.0 only.